# Execute code when subscribed pipe detects change

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component which dynamically changes its content in connection with the selected element. The component gets its content from a mock which contains an array of cases.

Additionally I have a link which can be clicked to display the next entry.

To detect this change I added this to on init:

```
case: Case;
cases = CASES;

...

ngOnInit() {
    this.route.paramMap.pipe(
      map(paramMap => +paramMap.get('id')),
    switchMap((id: number) => this.caseService.getCase(id)),
    ).subscribe(cases => this.case = cases);
    this.loadData();
  }
```

As you can see, located in `ngOnInit` is also a function called `loadData()`:

```
loadData(): void {
    this.color = this.case.header;
    this.images.push(this.case.image, this.case.image2, this.case.image3);
    this.carouselImage = this.images[this.counter];
    this.nextImage = this.images[this.nextCounter];
    this.prevImage = this.images[this.prevCounter];

    if (this.case.id === this.cases.length) {
      this.nextIndex = 0;
    } else {
      this.nextIndex = this.case.id + 1;
    }
  }
```

Now if the user clicks the mentioned link, the selected case gets changed and displayed, but `loadData()` won't be executed, since the page won't reload.

I additionally tried to call `loadData()` in `(click)`, but it seems that `loadData()` still works with the old case.

**Is there a way to call execute `loadData()` when the subscribed pipe detects a change?**

Comment: `.subscribe(cases => {this.case = cases;
    this.loadData(); });`?

Comment: @JBNizet Works kind of, but somehow `this.images.push(..)` won't load the new image urls (`this.case.header` does). Even though `console.log(this.case)` returns the new case, `console.log(this.images)` returns the old array.

Comment: Got it, had to empty the array - thank you!

Comment: @Tim when you use `this.images.push` you're actually mutating an existing array and change detection won't trigger, but if you spread operator, it will change reference and CD will trigger. eg. `this.images = [...this.images, this.case.image]`